# How to use a Visual Studio macro instead of system enviroment variable

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that always requires to set a system variable for the sources path, like: `c:\Project\Sources`.

Now I do not want to replace the system variable with one of the Visual Studios macros, like: `$SolutionDir`, which will point to `c:\Project\Sources\ProjectName`. So to get the path I want, I did something like this: `$(SolutionDir\..)`. (Inside `Include Aditional Directories`)

But it seems that this doesn't work. Whats the thing I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(SolutionDir)..
```

instead. You need to close the parenthesis first. $(SolutionDir) already contains a trailing '\'.